# How to simplify the logical expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1) $\lnot$(P$\rightarrow$(Q$\lor$$\lnot$Q))

$\lnot$($\lnot$P$\lor$(Q$\lor$$\lnot$Q))

P$\land$($\lnot$Q$\land$Q)

=P

2) (P$\rightarrow$P)$\lor$($\lnot$Q$\rightarrow$Q)

($\lnot$P$\lor$P)$\lor$($\lnot$$\lnot$Q$\lor$Q)

($\lnot$P$\lor$P)$\lor$(Q$\lor$Q)

= Q

Both of these are incorrect. Where did I go wrong?

How do I do this the correct way?

Comment: For (2), look very attentively at $\neg P\vee P$ and keep in mind that you'd be correct **if** the expression were $(\neg P\vee P)\wedge (Q\vee Q)$ instead.

Comment: For (1), look very attentively at $\neg Q\wedge Q$ and keep in mind that you'd be correct **if** the expression were $P\vee(\neg Q\wedge Q)$ instead.

Comment: Why first one is wrong? It seems correct.

Comment: @Amar $\neg Q \land Q = \bot$ ... so what is $P \land \bot$?